# Googe maps web API The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, google-maps

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I'm currently working on a web app using google maps api but I keep getting error **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.** the below code is recommended and said to work but I just can't seem to get it working. I'm running on localhost and this is within a .cs class.

```
 public string reverseGeocoding(string latlng)
    {
        //samplelatlng value 
        //latlng ="- 26.1946929,28.042508699999985"
        var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?location="+ latlng + "&sensor=false");

        var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

        var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
        var address = result.Element("formatted_address").ToString();
        return address;
        //var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
        //var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
        //var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");

        //formatted_address
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the variable `latlong` is passed in correctly? Usually when you get "Bad Request 400" with public APIs like Google Maps, means there is an actual problem with the request. Make sure there are no spaces in the `latlong` variable. I would print your requestUri to see what it looks like.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?location=-26.1946929,28.042508699999985&sensor=false  this is what it looks like thanks

Comment: When I browse it funny enough I get the results back.

Comment: it was location it's supposed to be latlng

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tutorials I found had location as the parameter it's supposed to be latlng cause I am passing latlng I feel pretty dumb thank you I know.

```
var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=false");
```